# Повторный запрос на сервер без логина\пароля

Tags: android

Опишу вкратце принцип.
Приложение отправляет GET запрос авторизации на сервер вида

```
Host/Data?login=arslanali&password=arslanali
```

Получаем JSON ответ с данными которые записываются в базу SQLite после чего отображаются пользователю. Логин и пароль не хранятся в базе SQLite. Пользователь изменяет статус записи.

Записывать с шифрованием логин и пароль в базу и отправлять вышеупомянутый запрос повторно думаю не правильно.
Как правильно реализовать обновление данных по кнопке "Обновить" на ActionBar?

Comment: Открывайте на сервере сессию, возвращайте в ответ на логин какой-то токен, и по нему запрашивайте обновление данных. К `ActionBar` вопрос отношения не имеет, если я правильно его понял.

Comment: Вы правильно поняли. ActionBar это пример того где я буду реализовывать обновление.

Comment: Дело в том, что ваш пример абсолютно неуместен, и сбивает с толку тех, кто потенциально мог бы помочь вам ,прочитав заголовок вашего вопроса. Но видит там ActionBar, и думает "я ничего не понимая в экшнбаре, я не смогу помочь".

Comment: Вы правы, спасибо.